# Android Service Geolocation

Tags: android, geolocation

I have one Android Service. This Service launch one class for geolocation. This is the code.

```
public class Localizar implements LocationListener {
private LocationManager manejador;
private Context context;
private DBAdapter db;

public Localizar(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    db = new DBAdapter(context);
}

public void start() {
    manejador = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (manejador.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {

        manejador.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 500, 0, this);

    }else  {

    }
}

public void stop() {
    manejador.removeUpdates(this);
}

private void saveData(double longitude, double latitude) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "G R A B A N D O   D A T O S", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
}


public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    saveData(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String proveedor) {
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String proveedor) {
}

public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle bundle) {
}
```

}
My problem is that the method onLocationChanged never executed. What have I done wrong ?
Thank you!
I tried it on another phone and it works correctly, maybe my phone is broken. I have a samsung galaxy DUOS.....

Comment: how are you testing your code. on device or emulator ?

Comment: Did you get any errors? Check logs 1st

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot reasons why you don't get `onLocationChanged`

If you run it in Service try add `Looper.getMainLooper()`, like:

```
 manejador.requestLocationUpdates(
                                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                            500,
                                            0,
                                            this,
                                            Looper.getMainLooper()
                                            );
```